# cakephp 3 download mulitiple files as a zip file

Tags: php, cakephp, zip, cakephp-3.x

I need to download multiple files as a zip file based on the following constraints

- i have stored the files with #id as as a name, while downloading need to change this one to the name stored in the db for that #id
- need to check the combined size of all the files which need to be downloaded
- Compress into zip and send it to client, need not be stored in server

Comment: There's no question in your question, it's just a list of tasks. Please describe the specific technical problems that you are facing with implementing the listed tasks.

Comment: @ndm currently im trying use php zipArchive class to export the group of files into zip, which im not able to do. it is showing Error: Class 'App\Controller\ZipArchive' not found.  in above i have used zipclass to rename the files too. i need a way to do  this one in cakephp3.